# Magento 2: Customizable Options disappear after upgrade to 2.1.7 from 2.1.4

Tags: magento2, custom-options, admin-panel

We've upgraded **Magento 2** from **2.1.4 to 2.1.7**, after the successful upgrade we see some customize-able options are not there, please find the below link:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Yes, iam facing the same issue

Comment: Having the same issue